# Delivery instructions do not appear on order confirmation email or at invoice

Tags: magento-1.9, delivery

When checking out the customer has the ability to add delivery instructions to their order on the checkout page (leave arrangement at door, recipient may be slow answering the door, call in case no one is home, etc.). However, on the order confirmation page I get this message does not appear.

Comment: try this module https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-delivery-instructions.html